# Permissions(user has not created list item but should only be able to edit their own)

Tags: list, permissions, active-directory, list-item

Hope you can help.

Ok so I have a list with a field called Owner which is derived from the active directory, this is the person who should be able to edit the list item in which they are assigned to. They will not create the list item which includes their name but must be able to edit their own and no other users(owners) assigned list item/s.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Emma

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported by SharePoint, so you need to set specific permission on each item, which will only perform well if you have a limited number of items in the list.

The setting of permission, can be done:

- Manually like this:

  - Open list with item
  - Select the item
  - In the ribbon click Item Permissions
  - In the ribbon click Stop Inheriting Permissions (and OK)
  - Select all users/groups with too many rights
  - In the ribbon click Remove User Permissions (and OK)
  - In the ribbon click Grant Permissions
  - Select the owner grant Contribute permissions OK
  - Repeat for other missing permissions
- With SharePoint designer workflow using custom activities like http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/
- Using code in an event receiver

Comment: Ok Thanks. Can I create item level permissions on InfoPath?

Comment: Well, if you save the items using code behind, then you can extend that to set the item level permissions, but if not then I'd recommend the other options

Comment: How would I go about setting the item level permissions manually?

Comment: I've added to the answer, but would not recommend that way unless the list is very small

Comment: ok Thanks but they would be able to edit other owners information in the list

Comment: The moment the Item level permissions is in place only the users added here (and site collection admin) will be able to edit that item

Comment: Btw you have some item permissions action with standard SPD 2010 workflow if you use Impersontation Step. Maybe AddToCurrentScopeOnly and Event Receiver is an option if its a lot of items, tbh I haven't tested that.